Intermittent CPU Usage Limitation During PyTorch Training on Windows (Jupyter Notebook)
I'm facing an issue with my PyTorch model training on Windows 10 using Jupyter Notebook. I've written a Python script to train a LSTM model over 500 epochs. The training process sometimes uses 100% of the CPU, which is expected and desired, but other times it inexplicably drops to only ~33% usage, which significantly slows down the training.
Here are some details about my setup :
Operating System: Windows 11
IDE: Jupyter Notebook
Python Version: Python 3.12.4
PyTorch Version: 2.3.1
CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700

What I've Tried:

Thread Configuration: I made sure to set the number of threads in PyTorch to the maximum available on my CPU:

import torch torch.set_num_threads(n)  # Where n is the number of CPU cores

Other Processes: Verified that no other resource-intensive processes are running concurrently.

Questions:
- What might be causing this intermittent drop in CPU usage?
- Are there additional configurations or steps I should consider to ensure consistent CPU utilization?
- Could this be an issue with Jupyter Notebook, and would running the script outside of Jupyter potentially help?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can this be considered a periodic drop? It could just be that different operations performed during the epoch are parallelized in different ways

I am not sure if this is due to periodic drops. The issue is somewhat random. Sometimes when I run the same training process multiple times a day, the CPU usage hits 100%, but other times it only reaches about 33%, even though I'm using the same code and data.

Is your data preloaded into memory or are you loading from disk? If loading from disk, you might be i/o bound for part of the dataset
